# Azure Managed Application Web App with Settings

Tags: azure-managed-app

I need to deploy an Asp.Net Core web application in **Azure Marketplace**.

I saw the following sample
https://github.com/Azure/azure-managedapp-samples/tree/master/Managed%20Application%20Sample%20Packages/201-managed-web-app

Is there a way to let the user create/edit some App Settings fields on the portal and to read those App Settings in the web app hosted inside de VM?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would take these fields in as part of your CreateUIDefinition and you could run these using the [Template Deployment Scripts preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template?tabs=CLI).

Another option could be to use [Azure Custom Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/custom-providers/overview) and [trigger an Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/custom-providers/tutorial-custom-providers-function-setup). This could be reused if you wanted to allow the user to call the Custom Provider later with your [ViewDefinition's Portal UX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/concepts-view-definition#commands) to update any of this information collected later via a Custom Action.